# Google App Engine: create_bulk_loader_config returns errno8

Tags: python, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am using the appcfg.py command

```
create_bulkloader_config --filename=bulkloader.yaml --url=http://myappid.appengine.com/_ah/remote_api
```

in order to generate the bulkloader.yaml of my datastore.

The problem is I am getting this error

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known>
FINISHED
```

I am using Mavericks and Python 2.7 and I am using appcfg from Eclipse Pydev

Comment: Are you still having this issue? Can you please provide the full stack trace?